# How to change iOS's device's locale using Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Anybody knows how to change iOS's device's locale using Xamarin Forms, without using the Settings App?

Please add a comment if you down vote. Thank you very much.

**Update**

What I wanted is control the NavigationPage button for RTL.

This documentation says a limitation on NavigationPage's button location is controlled by device locale:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/right-to-left

**Update**

My objective was controlling the NavigationPage, Xamarin's documentation pointed to change device locale, and I get the idea from there. It should be better if it's just application level.

Comment: Have you checked this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/

Comment: Yes, I did check that page. Their is a limitation on the NavigationPage button location where it says it is controlled by device locale. That is what I wanted to change, the device locale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Xamarin Forms I suggest making a dependency service. Make an interface like this:

```
public interface ILanguageSwitcher
{
    void ChangeAppLocale(string locale);
}
```

Create an implementation of your interface for iOS:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(LanguageSwitcher))]
namespace MyApp.iOS
{
    class LanguageSwitcher : ILanguageSwitcher
    {
        public void ChangeAppLocale(string locale)
        {
            var iOSLocale = locale.Replace('-', '_');

            NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetValueForKey(NSArray.FromStrings(iOSLocale), new NSString("AppleLanguages"));
            NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.Synchronize();
        }
    }
}
```

Note in iOS the locale would be "en_US" for US English and not "en-US".

Call this dependency from your Xamarin Forms code:

```
ILanguageSwitcher _languageSwitcher = DependencyService.Get<ILanguageSwitcher>();

private void LanguagePicker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var newItem = LanguagePicker.SelectedItem as CultureInfo;

    if (_languageSwitcher != null)
    {
        _languageSwitcher.ChangeAppLocale(newItem.Name);
    }
}
```

For Right-to-Left changes to take effect, such as with Hebrew or Arabic (and vice versa) the app needs to restart.